# How to write a prolog query that calculates the total salary and less than a value?

Tags: prolog

```
family(person( john, cohen, date(17,may,1990), unemployed), person( lily, cohen, date(9,may,1990), unemployed),[ ] ).
family(person( john, armstrong, date(7,may,1988), unemployed), person( lily, armstrong, date(29,may,1961), unemployed), [ ] ).
family(person( eric, baily, date(7,may,1963), works( bbc, 2200)), person( grace, baily, date(9,may,1965), works( ntu, 1000)), [person( louie, baily, date(25,may,1983), unemployed) ] ).
family(person( eric, baily, date(7,may,1963), works( acc, 21200)), person( grace, baily, date(9,may,1965), works( ntnu, 12000)), [person( louie, baily, date(25,may,1983), unemployed) ] ).
family(person( eric, fox, date(27,may,1970), works( bbc, 25200)), person( grace, fox, date(9,may,1971), works( ntbu, 13000)), [person( louie, fox, date(5,may,1993), unemployed) ] ).

husband(X) :- family(X, _, _).
wife(X) :- family(_, X, _).
child(X) :- family(_, _, Children), member(X, Children).

salary(person(_, _, _, works(_, S)), S).
salary(person(_, _, _, unemployed), 0).
```

A.Write a prolog rule totalIncome/2 to compute the total income of a family.
B. Write a prolog query to print total income of each family.
C. Write a prolog query to print family details of each family that has income per
family member less than 2000.
D. Write a prolog query to print family details of each family where children’s total
income is more than their parents.

for part A and B :

```
totalFamilyIncom(X,Y,Sum):- Sum is X+Y.

sum(Sumx,Sum):- foldl(totalFamilyIncom,Sumx,0,Sum).

totalIncome(family(X,Y,T), Income):- 
                      family(X,Y,T),
                      maplist(salary,[X,Y|T], L), 
                      sum(L,Income).
/* ? totalIncome(Family,TotalIncome).*/
```

but in part C and D it gives False???

```
totalx([],0).
totalx([Person|L],Sum):-
    salary(Person,S),
    totalx(L,Rest),
    Sum is S+Rest.

total_income(family(husband,wife,child),I):-
        totalx([husband,wife|child],I).
total_income(family(husband,wife,child),I):-
      I<2000.
```

can someone explain to me why it doesn't work???

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake - maybe just a typo - it's here

```
[husband,wife|child]
```

This is not a proper list (the tail should be a list, but there we have an atom), then totalx/2 will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track.

C) The question asks you to print family details of families that have income per family member less than 2000. In other words, the average income less than 2000. Since the question asks you to write a query, you shouldn't add another rule i.e. "total_income". To get the desired result using your code, your query would have to look like this:

```
 ?- family(Husband, Wife, Child), 
    totalx([Husband, Wife|Child], I), 
    length([Husband, Wife|Child], NumFamMembers), 
    I/NumFamMembers<2000.
```

This will print the details of each family from your database with average income less than 2000. *Note the use of capital letters for variables.*

D) Again it's asking for a query, so there is no need to write another rule, your totalx rule already gives you what you need.

```
?- family(Husband,Wife,Child),
   totalx(Children,IChildren),
   totalx([Husband],IHusband),
   totalx([Wife],IWife),
   IChildren > IHusband+IWife.
```

This query will result in the family details of families where the children's total income is greater than their parents. Although you probably don't care or have figured it out by now, hopefully this helps someone else out.